# How to find deleted partition

Tags: fdisk, partition-table, testdisk

I have some partition table with three partitions. I deleted the third partition with `fdisk` and next I created new partition on the same place with the same "first and last sectors". How can I determine if the deleted partition ever existed (I don't want to recover it).

Screenshots of what I did:

- third partition before deletion:

  [image]
- third partition file system before deletion:

  [image]
- deleting the third partition (reboot system after):

  [image]
- new third partition after deletion old third partition:

  [image]
- new third partition file system after deletion old third partition file system:

  [image]
- With TestDisk we can see partition table:

  [image]

So again: how can I determine if the deleted partition ever existed? Maybe with TestDisk or somehow different?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I added pictures just in case. I want to define if the deleted partition ever existed. Maybe it will be traces (footprints) of the old file system of the partition. I'm interested in absolutely any traces

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "define if the deleted partition ever existed". Changing the partition table doesn't change the contents of the partition, so you can try if there's something that looks like a file system on the harddisk in the area described by the partition (but you say you "don't want to recover" it). As far as the partition table is concerned, when you define the third partition the old data is overwritten, so you cannot see if there was different data in there before.

Comment: @dirkt Thank you very much, you helped me a lot!